# Finding cells of a .stl file with negative mean curvature using VTK in python

Tags: python, opengl, mesh, vtk

I have a `.stl` file and i'm trying to find the coordinates of cells with negative mean curvature using VTK and python. I have wrote these codes which are working fine to change the colors of cells based on their mean curvature but what i'm willing to achieve is coordinates of exact cells and triangles with specific mean curvature, e.g. 3d coordinates of cells with most negative mean curvature.
Here are the codes:

```
import vtk


def gaussian_curve(fileNameSTL):
    colors = vtk.vtkNamedColors()

    reader = vtk.vtkSTLReader()
    reader.SetFileName(fileNameSTL)
    reader.Update()

    curveGauss = vtk.vtkCurvatures()
    curveGauss.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
    curveGauss.SetCurvatureTypeToGaussian() # SetCurvatureTypeToMean() works better in the case of kidney.

    ctf = vtk.vtkColorTransferFunction()
    ctf.SetColorSpaceToDiverging()
    p1 = [0.0] + list(colors.GetColor3d("MidnightBlue"))
    p2 = [1.0] + list(colors.GetColor3d("DarkRed"))
    ctf.AddRGBPoint(*p1)
    ctf.AddRGBPoint(*p2)
    cc = list()
    for i in range(256):
        cc.append(ctf.GetColor(float(i) / 255.0))

    lut = vtk.vtkLookupTable()
    lut.SetNumberOfColors(256)
    for i, item in enumerate(cc):
        lut.SetTableValue(i, item[0], item[1], item[2], 1.0)
    lut.SetRange(0, 0) # In the case of kidney, the (0, 0) worked better.
    lut.Build()

    cmapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    cmapper.SetInputConnection(curveGauss.GetOutputPort())
    cmapper.SetLookupTable(lut)
    cmapper.SetUseLookupTableScalarRange(1)

    cActor = vtk.vtkActor()
    cActor.SetMapper(cmapper)

    return cActor


def render_scene(my_actor_list):
    renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    for arg in my_actor_list:
        renderer.AddActor(arg)
    namedColors = vtk.vtkNamedColors()
    renderer.SetBackground(namedColors.GetColor3d("SlateGray"))

    window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
    window.SetWindowName("Render Window")
    window.AddRenderer(renderer)

    interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    interactor.SetRenderWindow(window)

    # Visualize
    window.Render()
    interactor.Start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fileName = "400_tri.stl"
    my_list = list()
    my_list.append(gaussian_curve(fileName))
    render_scene(my_list)
```

This code produce red cells for positive mean curvature and blue for negative ones.[image: result of above code]

I need the result(coordinates of cells) in the form of arrays or something like that.
I would appreciate any suggestion and help on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution with [vtkplotter](https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter):

```py
from vtkplotter import *

torus1 = Torus().addCurvatureScalars().addScalarBar()
print("list of scalars:", torus1.scalars())

torus2 = torus1.clone().addScalarBar()
torus2.threshold("Gauss_Curvature", vmin=-15, vmax=0)

show(torus1, torus2, N=2) # plot on 2 separate renderers

print("vertex coordinates:", len(torus2.coordinates()))
print("cell centers      :", len(torus2.cellCenters()))
```

[**check out the resulting screenshot here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azvkJ.png)

Additional example [here](https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter/blob/master/examples/basic/mesh_threshold.py).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i'm trying to stick to vtk llibrary only. Also i will add an answer.

Comment: You're weolcome, consider that vtkplotter is not meant as a new/independent software, but it's a _helper_ module to vtk. E.g. `torus2` in the example above is a `vtkActor `object (with extended functionality).

Answer (score 1):

So i found the answer from [kitware weblog](https://blog.kitware.com/improved-vtk-numpy-integration-part-2/), here is the code that works fine using `vtk.numpy_interface` and `vtk.util.numpy_support`, but still it does not produce the `normals_array` and i don't know why??

```
import vtk
from vtk.numpy_interface import dataset_adapter as dsa
from vtk.util.numpy_support import vtk_to_numpy


def curvature_to_numpy(fileNameSTL, curve_type='Mean'):
    colors = vtk.vtkNamedColors()

    reader = vtk.vtkSTLReader()
    reader.SetFileName(fileNameSTL)
    reader.Update()
    # Defining the curvature type.
    curve = vtk.vtkCurvatures()
    curve.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
    if curve_type == "Mean":
        curve.SetCurvatureTypeToMean()
    else:
        curve.SetCurvatureTypeToGaussian()
    curve.Update()

    # Applying color lookup table.
    ctf = vtk.vtkColorTransferFunction()
    ctf.SetColorSpaceToDiverging()
    p1 = [0.0] + list(colors.GetColor3d("MidnightBlue"))
    p2 = [1.0] + list(colors.GetColor3d("DarkOrange"))
    ctf.AddRGBPoint(*p1)
    ctf.AddRGBPoint(*p2)
    cc = list()
    for i in range(256):
        cc.append(ctf.GetColor(float(i) / 255.0))

    lut = vtk.vtkLookupTable()
    lut.SetNumberOfColors(256)
    for i, item in enumerate(cc):
        lut.SetTableValue(i, item[0], item[1], item[2], 1.0)
    lut.SetRange(0, 0)  # In the case of kidney, the (0, 0) worked better.
    lut.Build()

    # Creating Mappers and Actors.
    mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    mapper.SetInputConnection(curve.GetOutputPort())
    mapper.SetLookupTable(lut)
    mapper.SetUseLookupTableScalarRange(1)

    actor = vtk.vtkActor()
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)

    # Scalar values to numpy array. (Curvature).
    dataObject = dsa.WrapDataObject(curve.GetOutput())
    normals_array = dataObject.PointData['Normals'] # Output array.
    curvature_array = dataObject.PointData['Mean_Curvature'] # output array.

    # Node values to numpy array.
    nodes = curve.GetOutput().GetPoints().GetData()
    nodes_array = vtk_to_numpy(nodes)

    # Creating a report file (.vtk file).
    writer = vtk.vtkPolyDataWriter()
    writer.SetFileName('vtk_file_generic.vtk')
    writer.SetInputConnection(curve.GetOutputPort())
    writer.Write()

   #  EDIT:

   # Creating the point normal array using vtkPolyDataNormals().
    normals = vtk.vtkPolyDataNormals()
    normals.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())  # Here "curve" could be replaced by "reader".
    normals.ComputePointNormalsOn()
    normals.SplittingOff()
    normals.Update()
    dataNormals = dsa.WrapDataObject(normals.GetOutput())
    normals_array = dataNormals.PointData["Normals"]



    return actor, normals_array, curvature_array, nodes_array


def render_scene(my_actor_list):
    renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    for arg in my_actor_list:
        renderer.AddActor(arg)
    namedColors = vtk.vtkNamedColors()
    renderer.SetBackground(namedColors.GetColor3d("SlateGray"))

    window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
    window.SetWindowName("Render Window")
    window.AddRenderer(renderer)

    interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    interactor.SetRenderWindow(window)

    # Visualize
    window.Render()
    interactor.Start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = "400_tri.stl"
    my_list = list()
    my_actor, my_normals, my_curve, my_nodes = curvature_to_numpy(filename, curve_type="Mean")
    my_list.append(my_actor)
    render_scene(my_list) # Visualization.
    print(my_nodes) # Data points.
    print(my_normals) # Normal vectors.
    print(my_curve) # Mean curvatures.
```

Comment: Maybe check that you are getting a normal array within the polydata.

polydata = curves.GetOutput()
normals = polydata.GetPointData().GetNormals()
print(normals)

Comment: I edited the code and added the computation of normal arrays. I used normals.`ComputePointNormalsOn()` to calculate normal vectors at each vertex and i don't know whether it's right or wrong?